# Python 3, parsing json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Please help, i'm getting this error:

```
with open('Data/language.json') as settings_file:
TypeError: Required argument 'flags' (pos 2) not found
```

My code is:

```
import json

with open('Data/settings.json') as settings_file:    
    Settings = json.load(settings_file)
```

Comment: Did you happen to do `from os import open`? `open` (the built-in `open` that you don't need to import) automatically defaults to read mode.

Comment: yes, i did, i removed it and it works now, thanks :)

Comment: @Blender: Make it an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you imported `open` from the `os` module with something like:

```
from os import open
```

`os.open` isn't the same as the builtin `open` function (which you don't need to import). Remove that import and you'll use the builtin `open`, which defaults to read mode.